# Merge two list and Subtract the values of List B From List A

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have the following lists and I want to subtract the property `Count` of list `B` from list `A`

Here are sample lists. Note that i've actually using Linq-To-Entities:

**List A**

```
List<Leave> defaultLeaves = new List<Leave>()
{
  new Leave{ Id = 1 , Count = 7},
  new Leave{ Id = 2 , Count = 7},
  new Leave{ Id = 3 , Count = 7},
  new Leave{ Id = 4 , Count = 3}
};
```

**List B**

```
List<Leave> usedLeaves = new List<Leave>()
 {
    new Leave{ Id = 1 , Count = 1},
    new Leave{ Id = 2 , Count = 2}        
  };
```

I want to have the output of the list to be like this by subtracting the count from list `A` using the count of list `B` by respective `Ids`

```
List<Leave> availableLeaves = new List<Leave>()
{
  new Leave{ Id = 1 , Count = 6},
  new Leave{ Id = 2 , Count = 5},
  new Leave{ Id = 3 , Count = 7},
  new Leave{ Id = 4 , Count = 3}
 };
```

is this possible using linq method???

Comment: The question and examples are to show the values but the application would be from the result sets of Ef

Comment: Then this question will be very misleading for future readers since you even have added the term List to the title. So a possible answer here will either not answer your question or not answer the question of future readers which use Linq-To-Objects.

Comment: Then can you suggest edits to match the point??

Comment: You should show the code where you query the database to fill the lists.

Comment: Fixed the whole question content! @TimSchmelter

Comment: yeah not aware i just ask the base of the question..

Comment: @doctor: Why? It's harder to read it now...

Answer (score 5):

IMO this is a perfect candidate for [`left outer join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

```
var availableLeaves = 
    (from d in defaultLeaves
     join u in usedLeaves on d.Id equals u.Id into match
     from u in match.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new Leave
     {
         Id = d.Id,
         Count = d.Count - (u != null ? u.Count : 0)
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Or `Count = d.Count - u?.Count ?? 0`.

Comment: This is the universal solution for Linq-To.Objects and other Linq providers like Linq-To-Entities.

Comment: this works I have to check performance against using firstOrDefault();

Answer (score 4):

You can use linq

```
var availableLeaves = defaultLeaves.Select(x => new Leave()
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Count = x.Count - usedLeaves.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.Id)?.Count ?? 0
}).ToList();
```

The main part is this line

```
Count = x.Count - usedLeaves.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.Id)?.Count ?? 0
```

`usedLeaves.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.Id)` gets the `Leave` with the same Id. If it does not exist then it is `null` so the whole `usedLeaves.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.Id)?.Count` is `null` and this cause to subtract zero which does not affect the count.

Comment: Sleeker one using ternary to handle 0

Comment: @EduCielo That's not ternary (which is actually called the conditional operator `? :`) that's the null coalescing operator `??` and the null conditional operator `?.`(which is only available in C# 6).

Comment: @juharr `?` is the _null propagation_ operator ;)

Comment: @RenéVogt Not according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).  Though that's what I would have called it.

Comment: @juharr seems there are different names out there, but you maybe right that _conditional_ is the official version.

Comment: I also thought that ? was the null propagation

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons I would turn `usedLeaves` into a dictionary:

```
var dic = usedLeaves.ToDictionary(l => l.Id, l => l.Count);
```

Then I would use this to generate the result list:

```
availableLeaves = defaultLeaves.Select(l => 
                     new Leave {Id = l.Id, Count = l.Count - dic[l.Id]})
                  .ToList();
```

Of course you might want to add some error handling if an `Id` of the first list is not contained in the second:

```
availableLeaves = defaultLeaves.Select(l => 
                  {
                     int count;
                     if (!dic.TryGetValue(l.Id, out count))
                         count = 0;                         
                     return new Leave {Id = l.Id, Count = l.Count - count});
                  }).ToList();
```

---

For bigger lists, turning the second into a dictionary is suggested as accessing the objects by `Id` this way is much faster than to look them up using `FirstOrDefault()` for every single leave.

*Update*: Did not take into account that we are talking about EF. So I'm not sure which is the better way. You would have to call `usedLeaves.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary()` if you want to load all those leaves at once and keep them on client side.
As I said, I'm not experienced enough to decide if this is better than seeking for every single one using consecutive `FirstOrDefault()` calls.

Comment: I think this gonna be use in entity framework. I doubt linq2EF supports ToDictionary

Comment: indeed.. I used it using EF

Comment: If `Id` is the primary key in `Leave` the `FirstOrDefault` will hit the index and it does not have any performance problem.

Comment: That's my point also. And i will try to figure out which one does better before i accept answers. FirstOrDefault is like querying the list ever single iteration??? (I Stand Corrected)

Comment: @EduCielo yes it would be called for every single leave, but as I said before, I'm not experienced in EF so I don't know how these calls are handled behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

And here is a one liner:

```
var leaves = defaultLeaves.GroupJoin(usedLeaves, dl => dl.Id, ul => ul.Id,
            (dl, ulList) => new Leave { Id = dl.Id, Count = dl.Count - (ulList.Any() ? ulList.FirstOrDefault().Count : 0) });
```

As Ivan Stoev suggested, this is a simple LEFT JOIN. The extension method which can do that is `GroupJoin()`